# Port X-Cart Module to Joomla (Cloudsearch) (might be impossible)

Tags: joomla, x-cart

I have an X-cart store with a Joomla front-end.  I have installed the x-cart module cloudsearch into my x-cart store.   It creates a little search box in the upper right corner to search my x-cart store's products and pages.  I would like for this box to also appear in my joomla sites header (which is the "front-end" for the store).   Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Sure, create a new module of type "Custom HTML" and paste your cart form there (if it's just ajax) or load it by url creating a module of type "Wrapper"

Comment: The search box is loaded into x-cart via smarty template (.tpl file).   I already tried adding all the CSS, JS, HTML to the Joomla index file but it still didn't work.  There is no database connectivity with x-cart which is where the data is being pulled from for the dynamic real-time results.  Also, none of the x-cart variables or the smarty templating engine are available on the joomla side.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this required finding the libraries for the module (mainly handlebars.js and hoverintent.js) and making sure those were being loaded via the joomla header.  Also had to add CSS from the modules template directory as well.  Then I used "view source" to get the generated javascript source to initiate cloudsearch, as well as get the dynamically generated html for the search box I was using.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.  In the end it ended up being just a matter of getting the javascript, css, and html right.  All the database connectivity and search features are controlled by an external js file loaded from the cloudsearch server.